# Multiple SELECT with NOT IN - inner Select statement returns empty and the whole SELECT returns empty

Tags: sql, oracle, select, multiple-select

There are two table **TABLE1** and **TABLE2** in which there is a common field **ID**. I wanted to retrieve values from **TABLE2** that doesnot match in **TABLE1** based on **ID** value.

```
select * from TABLE2 where subject = 1 and ID NOT IN (select ID from TABLE1 where subject = 1)
```

**Sample:**

> TABLE1
>  ID SUBJECT  
>  1  1
>
> TABLE2
>  ID SUBJECT  
>  1  1 
>  2  1

The expected result is 2 and it works fine.

But when **TABLE1 is empty** or the **inner** `select ID from TABLE1 where subject = 1` returns empty, the whole select statement returns empty.
**But the expected result is 1, 2**

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `left join`

```
select t2.* 
from table2 t2
left outer join table1 t1 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.subject = 1
where t2.subject = 1
and t1.id is null
```

See a [good explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: This is not correct. The `where` clause turns the `left outer join` into an `inner join`.

Comment: With this an empty value is returned. when I removed t2.subject = 1 it works perfectly. But I could not understand why it needs to be removed.

Comment: After editing by Gordon Linoff it works fine. Thanks juergen and Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use not `exists` also for this work -

```
select * from TABLE2 where subject = 1 and NOT exists
(select 1 from TABLE1 where subject = 1 and table1.id = table2.id)
```